# Can't start Weston anymore

Tags: linux, graphics, opengl, display-driver, wayland

For a few weeks, I haven't been able to start Weston anymore on my Arch Linux machine.

My Graphics card is:

```
$ glxinfo  | grep 'renderer string'
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile
```

And my mesa version is 10.5.3.

And this is what I get when I try launching weston:

```
$ weston-launch

Date: 2015-04-14 CEST
[08:53:48.655] weston 1.7.0
               http://wayland.freedesktop.org
               Bug reports to: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Wayland&component=weston&version=1.7.0
               Build: 1.6.93-9-gdbd8606 configure.ac: bump to version 1.7.0 for release (2015-02-13 20:47:09 -0800)
[08:53:48.655] OS: Linux, 3.19.3-3-ARCH, #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 8 14:10:00 CEST 2015, x86_64
[08:53:48.655] Starting with no config file.
[08:53:48.655] Loading module '/usr/lib/weston/drm-backend.so'
[08:53:48.658] initializing drm backend
[08:53:48.659] using /dev/dri/card0
[08:53:48.659] Loading module '/usr/lib/weston/gl-renderer.so'
[08:53:48.703] failed to choose EGL config
[08:53:48.703] EGL error state: EGL_SUCCESS (0x3000)
[08:53:48.705] failed to initialize egl
[08:53:48.705] fatal: failed to create compositor
```

I've Googled around and I found that it might be a regression bug in mesa but that bug was for mesa 10.5.0 or older. So I'm wondering if it's actually a bug, if the bug is still there, and if there's a workaround for this.